# KafkaStream EXACTLY_ONCE in stream application results in failed to re-balance if one broker is down

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka streaming application with kafka-streams and kafka-clients both 2.4.0
with the following configs

```
properties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokers);
properties.put(StreamsConfig.PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG, StreamsConfig.EXACTLY_ONCE);
```

- brokers= ip1:port1, ip2:port2,ip3:port3,
- topic partition: 3
- topic replication : 3

**Scenario 1**: I start only 2 brokers (stream app still contains three ips of broker in broker ip setting) and when i start the my stream app the following error occurs.

```
2020-02-13 13:28:19.711  WARN 18756 --- [-1-0_0-producer] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=my-app1-a4c8867f-b914-49bb-bc58-203349700828-StreamThread-1-0_0-producer, transactionalId=my-app1-0_0] Connection to node -2 (/ip2:port2) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

and later after 1 minute

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: stream-thread [my-app1-a4c8867f-b914-49bb-bc58-203349700828-StreamThread-1] Failed to rebalance.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:852)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:743)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:698)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:671)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: stream-thread [my-app1-a4c8867f-b914-49bb-bc58-203349700828-StreamThread-1] task [0_0] Failed to initialize task 0_0 due to timeout.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.initializeTransactions(StreamTask.java:966)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.<init>(StreamTask.java:254)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.<init>(StreamTask.java:176)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$TaskCreator.createTask(StreamThread.java:355)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$TaskCreator.createTask(StreamThread.java:313)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$AbstractTaskCreator.createTasks(StreamThread.java:298)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.addNewActiveTasks(TaskManager.java:160)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.createTasks(TaskManager.java:120)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsRebalanceListener.onPartitionsAssigned(StreamsRebalanceListener.java:77)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.invokePartitionsAssigned(ConsumerCoordinator.java:272)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete(ConsumerCoordinator.java:400)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:421)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:340)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:471)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1267)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1231)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1211)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:843)
    ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired after 60000milliseconds while awaiting InitProducerId
```

I was Testing for High availability test scenarios. I think kafka should still work as **replications are present in the two brokers properly**(I have checked using kafka GUI tool).

**Scenario 2**: Today i noticed that when i start only 2 brokers and give the ips of theses two brokers (i.e. stream app only has the ip of two working brokers)

```
2020-02-16 16:18:24.818  INFO 5741 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=my-app-0a357371-525b-46cf-9fe1-34ee94fa4158-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=my-app] Group coordinator ip2:port2 (id: 2147483644 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
2020-02-16 16:18:24.818 ERROR 5741 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [my-app-0a357371-525b-46cf-9fe1-34ee94fa4158-StreamThread-1] Encountered the following unexpected Kafka exception during processing, this usually indicate Streams internal errors:

org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: stream-thread [my-app-0a357371-525b-46cf-9fe1-34ee94fa4158-StreamThread-1] Failed to rebalance.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:852)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:743)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:698)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:671)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: stream-thread [my-app-0a357371-525b-46cf-9fe1-34ee94fa4158-StreamThread-1] task [0_0] Failed to initialize task 0_0 due to timeout.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.initializeTransactions(StreamTask.java:966)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.<init>(StreamTask.java:254)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.<init>(StreamTask.java:176)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$TaskCreator.createTask(StreamThread.java:355)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$TaskCreator.createTask(StreamThread.java:313)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$AbstractTaskCreator.createTasks(StreamThread.java:298)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.addNewActiveTasks(TaskManager.java:160)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.createTasks(TaskManager.java:120)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsRebalanceListener.onPartitionsAssigned(StreamsRebalanceListener.java:77)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.invokePartitionsAssigned(ConsumerCoordinator.java:272)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete(ConsumerCoordinator.java:400)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:421)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:340)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:471)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1267)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1231)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1211)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:843)
    ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired after 60000milliseconds while awaiting InitProducerId
```

**Note**: This is not the case if i don['t set **EXACTLY_ONCE** in properties. Them it works as intended. 
Tried increasing reties and back off max ms but didn't help. 
Can anyone explain what i am missing?

**logs of broker2 when broker 1 is down:**

```
[2020-02-17 02:29:00,302] INFO [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=1, leaderId=3, fetcherId=0] Retrying leaderEpoch request for partition __consumer_offsets-36 as the leader reported an error: UNKNOWN_LEADER_EPOCH (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
```

Kafak logs are filled with the above line.

**Now One Major Observation**:
When I turn off broker2(ie. broker 1 and broker 3 are running) then my stream application runs fine.
**My App shuts down only when broker 1 is down.** I'm guessing some critical information that should be distributed between all brokers is only saved in broker 1.

Comment: What you say makes sense (can you reproduce the issue reliably?). In general, the producer should detect if a broker is down and connect to a different broker. What is unclear from your description is, what the exact order of event is? You start 2 broker and than the producer? You have 3 broker running, start the producer and kill one broker at the same time? You have 3 brokers and the producer running and kill one broker?

Comment: I'll update the questions with scenarios.

Comment: Do you start 2 completely new brokers? For this case, with default configs, the broker is not able to create the "transaction state" topic (the default replication is 3). Note that the "transactional topic" is not created if exactly-once is not used (but it's created lazily, ie, on first demand). When the producer inits it PID, the broker tries to create the "transaction state" topic, but it cannot because there are only 2 broker.s

Comment: Can you try to start 3 brokesr, run your app, stop one broker, and then restart the app? For this case, the "transactional topic" is created on the first run, and you can still use it one the second run, even if there are only 2 brokers. -- Btw: if creating the "transaction state" topic fails, the brokers logs it -- try to check out the broker logs if you can find such an error (just to verify my assumption about what happens).

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it and get back to you.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I have done what you said but the result is still the same. failed to rebalance.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax please read observations which I have updated in the question.

Comment: I am not sure -- not an expert on all the broker details. It seems to be some configuration problem though. Maybe reaching out to the Kafka mailing list or Confluent Community Slack can help.

Comment: Can you post your kafka stream config. try setting StreamsConfig.REPLICATION_FACTOR_CONFIG to 3.  Also have a look at it https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/StreamsConfig.java#L433

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I wasn't able to fix the above instead we used docker and ran Kafka inside it as Exactly_Once is working fine with ubuntu.