# Kafka Stream Application stuck re-balancing _transation_state with "exactly-once" semantics in Windows Kafka Cluster Failover

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, high-availability

I am running a 3 broker Kafka cluster with 3 zookeeper instances on Windows OS. We require a highly available cluster, to achieve zero downtime. Till now, all things were working, but when we tried to test the Failover scenario by shutting down one broker the Kafka stream application stuck and unable to consume further messages.
After taking too many efforts we get to know this behavior is happening only when we use the semantic exactly-once. The bigger confusion is that we are unable to reproduce this issue on Ubuntu or event in Docker. Following are the configurations:

Broker Configuration:

```
broker.id=1
zookeeper.connect=x.x.x.x1:2181,x.x.x.x2:2181,x.x.x.x3:2181
delete.topic.enable=false
num.partitions=3
default.replication.factor=3
transaction.state.log.num.partitions=3
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=3
transaction.state.log.min.isr=2
```

Stream Configurations:

```
 properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, applicationId);
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokers);
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, EventSerde.class.getName());
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, offsetPolicy);
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG, StreamsConfig.EXACTLY_ONCE);
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_DESERIALIZATION_EXCEPTION_HANDLER_CLASS_CONFIG, LogAndContinueExceptionHandler.class);
   properties.put(StreamsConfig.REPLICATION_FACTOR_CONFIG, 3);
```

Streams Configurations has "exactly-once" semantics enabled.
Is it really the issue of exactly-once or the OS or I am doing any wrong configurations?

Comment: Can you post your kafka stream config. try setting StreamsConfig.REPLICATION_FACTOR_CONFIG to 3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60203105/kafkastream-exactly-once-in-stream-application-results-in-failed-to-re-balance-i

Comment: I have added Stream configurations in the question. It already uses the REPLICATION_FACTOR_CONFIG = 3. And the same configurations are working fine on Ubuntu/ Docker.

Comment: That may indicate its an OS issue. What is the Kafka version? See this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6052